# Exception in thread "main" java.io.EOFException in Google my business

Tags: java, google-my-business-api

I am writing a code to extract insights for all the locations according to what is described here:
https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/insight-data?hl=en
Sometimes (and NOT always) while running the code I have this Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(ObjectInputStream.java:2736)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(ObjectInputStream.java:3211)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:896)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:358)
    at com.google.api.client.util.IOUtils.deserialize(IOUtils.java:171)
    at com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory$FileDataStore.<init>(FileDataStoreFactory.java:102)
    at com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory.createDataStore(FileDataStoreFactory.java:73)
    at com.google.api.client.util.store.AbstractDataStoreFactory.getDataStore(AbstractDataStoreFactory.java:55)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.StoredCredential.getDefaultDataStore(StoredCredential.java:171)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeFlow$Builder.setDataStoreFactory(AuthorizationCodeFlow.java:744)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow$Builder.setDataStoreFactory(GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.java:209)
```

Does anyone have any idea how I can fix this? Is it possible that the error is because I have many locations in my account and it is sending too many requests to GMB?

I try to share some abstract parts of the code:

```
    JSONObject jObj=new JSONObject();
        ReportLocationInsightsRequest content = new ReportLocationInsightsRequest();
        content.setFactory(JSON_FACTORY);
        BasicMetricsRequest basicRequest = new BasicMetricsRequest();
    
        content.setLocationNames(locationNamelist); // locationNamelist  is provided previousely in another function 
        List<MetricRequest> metricRequests= new ArrayList<MetricRequest>();
        MetricRequest metricR=new MetricRequest();
        String metric="ALL";
        metricR.setMetric(metric);
        metricRequests.add(metricR);
        timeRange.setStartTime(MyStartTime); // desired start time
        timeRange.setEndTime(MyEndTime); // desired end time
        basicRequest.setTimeRange(timeRange);
        basicRequest.setMetricRequests(metricRequests);
        content.setBasicRequest(basicRequest );
        TimeRange timeRange=new TimeRange();
    
           try {
                    MyBusiness.Accounts.Locations.ReportInsights locationReportInsight= 
                            mybusiness.accounts().locations().reportInsights(accName, content);
                    ReportLocationInsightsResponse response= locationReportInsight.execute();
            
                    jObj=new JSONObject(response);
            
                }catch(Exception e) {
        
                    System.out.println(" Exception "+ e);
            
                }
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Could be a network issue. Just guessing, though, as you didn't provide any code. Please see [ask].

Comment: Thanks a million, you are right. just the code is too long and very complicated .. I try to edit my question and if it is possible I add some abstract and meaningful parts of the code.